# Python Versioneer is not generating a -version.py file

Tags: python, versioning, python-versioneer

I am trying to add versioning to my current Python project.  I have installed Versioneer and setup the setup.cfg file to the best of my understanding of the documentation.  When I run versioneer install I receive an error stating it cannot find the _version.py file.  Below is the copy of the file and error I receive.

```
[versioneer]
VCS = git
style = pep440
versionfile_source = hw-assesment-tool/_version.py
versionfile_build = hw-assesment-tool/_version.py
tag_prefix =
parentdir_prefix =
```

and this is the error I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'hw-assesment-tool/_version.py'
```

Comment: My understanding is that running "versioneer install" is what's supposed to generate the _version.py file.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem with a similar setup.cfg file, but in a tiny project with no nested directories and I ended up needing to remove the directory in front of _version.py because the versioneer.py script searches from the directory that contains the setup.cfg and so it was trying to look in a directory that didn't exist.

I'm not sure how your file structure is set up but it might work if you try changing it to:

```
versionfile_source = _version.py
versionfile_build = _version.py
```

If all your source files are in the same directory as the setup.cfg then that should fix it.